# How to solve error "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'" in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I recently started to learn to use Angular 14, but I have a problem. I want to use the property "total" that was created in a component, but got that error "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'".

The app.component.html code is:

```
<div>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-total mensaje="Total por pagar: " total="5000"></app-total>
  <app-items></app-items>
</div>
```

While the component having the "total" property, total.component.ts is:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-total',
  templateUrl: './total.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./total.component.css']
})
export class TotalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() total:number = 0;
  @Input() mensaje:string = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: `[total]="5000"`

Comment: Weird. The first time I tried that, got a the error "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'", but now it suddenly works. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, this is the idiomatic way to pass a literal number or boolean value to an `@Input()` property. Unfortunately the Angular documentation on binding doesn't make this very clear, so I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) syntax for the value to be evaluated as a number:

```
<app-total mensaje="Total por pagar: " [total]="5000"></app-total>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-total mensaje="Total por pagar: "  [total]="5000"></app-total>
  <app-items></app-items>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a number directly as a number `@Input` to the component, or a `true`/`false` as a boolean `@Input`, or even an array, without using Angular's [Property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding), we can take advantage of functions and types of [Angular's CDK Coercion](https://material.angular.io/cdk/coercion/overview) (or create our own if we don't want to depend on [@angular/cdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cdk)).

For example, to pass a number `@Input` to the component, we can do the following:

```js
import { coerceNumberProperty, NumberInput } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';

@Input()
get total() { return this._total; }
set total(value: NumberInput) {
  // `coerceNumberProperty` turns any value coming in from the view into a number, allowing the
  // consumer to use a shorthand string while storing the parsed number in memory. E.g. the consumer can write:
  // `<app-total total="500"></app-total>` instead of `<app-total [total]="500"></app-total>`.
  // The second parameter specifies a fallback value to be used if the value can't be parsed to a number.
  this._total = coerceNumberProperty(value, 0);
}
private _total = 0;
```

Which allows the consumer to use a shorthand string while storing the parsed number in memory as follows:

```html
<app-total mensaje="Total por pagar: " total="5000"></app-total>
```

If we don't want to use the CDK's built-in functions and types, we can take a look at their definition in the Angular Components repo under [components/src/cdk/coercion](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/cdk/coercion) folder.

For example, we have to define the following type and functions to handle the [number property](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/coercion/number-property.ts):

```js
/**
 * Type describing the allowed values for a number input
 */
export type NumberInput = string | number | null | undefined;

/** Coerces a data-bound value (typically a string) to a number. */
export function coerceNumberProperty(value: any): number;
export function coerceNumberProperty<D>(value: any, fallback: D): number | D;
export function coerceNumberProperty(value: any, fallbackValue = 0) {
  return _isNumberValue(value) ? Number(value) : fallbackValue;
}

/**
 * Whether the provided value is considered a number.
 */
export function _isNumberValue(value: any): boolean {
  // parseFloat(value) handles most of the cases we're interested in (it treats null, empty string,
  // and other non-number values as NaN, where Number just uses 0) but it considers the string
  // '123hello' to be a valid number. Therefore we also check if Number(value) is NaN.
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(value as any)) && !isNaN(Number(value));
}
```

And the same for the functions and types of the [boolean-property](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/coercion/boolean-property.ts), [string-array](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/coercion/string-array.ts), and [array](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/coercion/array.ts).